# Creating columns in one dataframe only from non matching columns from another dataframe and set all values to 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df1

A    B    C
5    1    5
4    2    8
2    5    3

df2

A    B    C    D
4    3    4    1
3    5    1    2
1    2    5    4
```

df1 and df2 share the same columns names except "D" which is only found in df2. What I would like to do is add D to df1 but fill all rows with "0"'s

In other words, if a column exists in df2 but it doesn't in df1, add that column to df1 but make all values in that column 0 (below)

```
df1

A    B    C    D
5    1    5    0
4    2    8    0
2    5    3    0
```

I realize it would be very easy to add one column called "D" to df1 but this is just a dummy example when in reality I am dealing with much larger and many more dataframes. So, I am looking for a way to do this with a code I could implement in a loop or iteratively

Comment: I think the word `add` is getting confusing here. Seems like you simply want to create a column 'D' with the static value of 0 in df1, leaving everything else unchanged?

Comment: @ALollz that's correct. I will edit it to sound that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the missing columns with `Index.difference`.

Then there are a ton of ways to assign multiple columns with a static value to a DataFrame, so here's one where you unpack a dictionary where the keys are the column names and the values of that dict is the static value you want to assign.

```
df1 = df1.assign(**{x: 0 for x in df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)})

   A  B  C  D
0  5  1  5  0
1  4  2  8  0
2  2  5  3  0
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. However, is there any way to preserve the order of the columns? They seem to be added quite randomly

Comment: @Melderon check my answer. I believe it does that for you, too.

Comment: @richardec for some reason, it turned everything into a float. I just need "0" as the above answer provides. Thank you, though

Comment: @Melderon that's easy to fix. Just add `.astype(int)`, like in my answer.

Comment: @Melderon which columns are getting mis-ordered? The ones in DF1 or the ones in DF2 that are missing?

Comment: @ALollz the ones in DF1 from DF2. It's not a huge deal, just nice for looking through

Comment: @Melderon are you using an older version of python like <= 3.6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `fill_value`:

```
print(df1.add(df2, fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C    D
0  9  4  9  1.0
1  7  7  9  2.0
2  3  7  8  4.0
```

**Note**: This method will fill the **existing nan** in each dataframe with `0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df3 = df1.add(df2).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
   A  B  C  D
0  9  4  9  0
1  7  7  9  0
2  3  7  8  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) one dataframe using columns from another one:

```
df1.reindex(df2.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```